# What kind of functions are E1(...), E2(...) related to numerical linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, machine-learning

The question is related to this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06067.pdf

Unfortunately, the meaning of E1(T1,T2), E2(T3), with Tx meaning a tensor, are not specified. It can be found in the proof on the 11th page, which belongs to the theorem on the 4th page.

Could somebody help me what kind of function is Ex(...)?
Thank you!

Comment: They are defined in equations (3) (page 4) and (5) (page 10), the sign $:=$ for "is defined as" is rather common. Obviously, they are just short expressions for certain norms of differences.

Comment: Oh, I understand, thank you! ;)